How can I get every URL on my site with Astro including dynamic pages
I was working on a 404 page for my site and I wanted to add a did you mean link. I had already figured out how to find similar page URLs and how to transfer the list of all the URLs from the server to the client, so now I only need to know how to get this list of URLs. Not only that, but I have already tried using import.meta.glob but that doesn't resolve dynamic pages, which I would like to do if I can.

Because there doesn't seem to be any official solution, I have written a small script that can do this by importing all the Astro files with import.meta.glob and manually resolving all the dynamic pages using Regex, getStaticPages, and replaceAll:
const modules: any[] = await Promise.all(Object.values(import.meta.glob(['./**/*.astro'])).map(fn => fn()));
let paths: string[] = [];
for (const module of modules) {
  if (module.getStaticPaths == null) {
    paths.push(module.url == '' ? '/' : module.url);
    continue;
  }
  const staticPaths = (await Promise.resolve(module.getStaticPaths())).map((staticPath: any) => staticPath.params);
  staticPaths.forEach((staticPath: any) => {
    const path = module.url.replaceAll(/\[([^\]]+)\]/g, (match: string) => {
      return staticPath[match.substring(1).substring(0, match.length - 2)];
    });
    paths.push(path);
  });
};

There are multiple problems with this code block, of which the main one being that there are multiple instances of using any when there is no good type available instead of defining one myself, but it works temporarily as a workaround until there is a better solution.
